# Can I have a directory chooser in an Android application using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I know that html/javascript doesn't give a directory chooser for security reasons ,but what if I'm using phonegap to create an android application ,means I will create this application using html and javascript ,I read phonegap file API but I couldn't figure out a way to do that ,is there any example does the same ?? Any help would be really appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is reference link you may get answer

[PhoneGap's File API](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/9/PhoneGaps-File-API)

[Mobile File Explorer with PhoneGap/Cordova and](http://www.digitalnoiz.com/mobile-development/mobile-file-explorer-with-phonegapcordova-and-jquery-mobile-part-1/)